# Simplifying this expression involving complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I wish to reduce the following expression :
$$
\dfrac{\mathrm{i}\left(-4t+\sin\left(4\left(t-1\right)\right)+4\right)-\cos\left(4\left(t-1\right)\right)+1}{2{\pi}^2\left(t-1\right)^2}
$$
to get
$$
\left(\frac{\sin(2(t-1))}{\pi(t-1)}\right)^{2}
$$

Comment: are you sure your expression is correct? I wonder about the $t$ in the numerator of the first term.

Comment: I plug $t=0$ into your big expression and get something not a real number. But I plug $t=0$ into your second thing, and get a real number.

Comment: I need 10 minutes to fix my expression because I noticed a mistake. However, I have completely forgotten to use euler's relation and your answer might have ringed the bell

Comment: bells ringing is good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Euler's formula helps:
$$e^{-4 i(t-1)} \,=\, \cos({-4 (t-1)}) +i \sin({-4 (t-1)}) \,=\, \cos({4 (t-1)}) -i \sin({4 (t-1)}). $$

From there, you might use well-known formulas for $\cos(2\theta)$ and $\sin(2\theta)$.